# JavaScript appearing on the page with "inline-block" css inherited

Tags: javascript, css

We're using display: inline-block; to control elements that might live within the div of class "test". The javascript is now appearing on the page. I did not know "script" tags could ever render to the page. Has anyone found a way to work this example code to not hit elements such as "style" and "script"?

We're willing to use display:none; on our script and style tags but that's a kludge.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .test * {
            display: inline-block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="test">
        <p>Text here</p>    
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function TestFunction() {
                var test = 1;
            };
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The output is:

Text here function TestFunction() { var test = 1; };

Comment: `.test script { display: none; }`, but it's better not to write selectors like `.test *` or put `script` tags deep into document.

Comment: `.test *` is more of a kludge

Comment: Why not just move the scripts into the head like they should be?

Comment: ..or at the bottom of the page. Either way, why make work for yourself. A script doesn't belong within a page element.

Comment: crazy, I've never seen this in 15 years of javascript-usage

Comment: Our CMS dynamically inserts script tags throughout the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to change the `.test * {}` selector.

An alternate would be to bulldoze the style with something like:

```
script,style{
   display:none !important;
}
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JWells/uTEAL/)

Comment: Yes we had tested this solution but we weren't sure we wanted to kludge hide scripts that shouldn't appear anyway.

Comment: I understand. A better solution would be to un-kludge your css selector. I think the 'kludginess' of this solution depends on your need for your `.test * {}` selector vs some other, better selector.

Comment: We're going with this one since the time-constraints encourage using the * and "display:none" is the default for script tags. Chrome and Firefox both show the scripts and both respond to the fix above.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite it with `display: none;` or you can use the `:not()` selector like so:

```
.test *:not(script) {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Or, probably the best option would be to place your script tags just inside your `</body>` tag or in the head where they should go.

Comment: *or in the head where they should go*.. actually the suggestion is to put all your `script` tags before `</body>` and also `:not` is supported only in modern browsers.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Good point about the script tags and modern browsers. If OP is not concerned about <IE9 support then it's no big deal though.

Comment: I'm afraid that in 2014 we still have to be afraid of everything. The age of free-to-use CSS3 is still to come :(

Comment: Indeed: "not concerned about <IE9 support "

Answer (score 0):

Just like you commented before, 
"We're willing to use display:none; on our script and style tags but that's a kludge."
You're setting the  tag to spill its guts with that 
`.test * {display: inline-block}`

A couple of things you could do.

1. Take out the  tag from within that div
2. Don't use the * selector in CSS
3. Add another rule within css `.test script {display: none;}`